# Electron application auto updating using Squirrel

Tags: javascript, npm, electron, squirrel.windows

I am trying to build an application using Node.js and Electron. I know the automatic updates are possible for these applications since applications like Slack and Atom are using this feature. This can be achieved using Squirrel or electron-updater but couldn't find a proper way to accomplish that. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd begin with taking a look at http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.36.8/api/auto-updater/. I am not sure your question is specific enough to otherwise give you proper help.